# How to make Wordpress categories as subdomains without using a plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress

I was using a plugin called wordpress subdomains 0.6.9 but it has lots of bugs and creating subdomains with this version is risky, I mean later there will be lots of broken links, so is there any way to do this manually, by editing the php code or database values ? 
or anything else that will make this work ?
and thank you :D

Comment: Why would you not like to use a plugin ? Isn't that one of the most awesome things of WordPress ?

Answer (score 2):

Just an idea: create a wildcard subdomain within your apache config (assuming you´re using apache webserver) and let it point to a php script which redirects acording to the given subdomain.

Comment: That is interesting  - but  how would such a script work ? what would it check for ?

Comment: Compare to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18539141/how-do-i-get-htaccess-to-redirect-from-wildcard-subdomain-page-to-wildcard-subd

Comment: The redirect is understood and easy.. the php script part was my comment subject..

Comment: The script would extract the called URL from the HTTP request, you can parse this URL then and do whatever you like to do :) See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292937/php-function-to-get-the-subdomain-of-a-url

Answer (score 2):

Are you using Apache2 + permalink? If so, craft some `RewriteRule` within `.htaccess` could do it (along with the original permalink).

For example

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} cat1.my.site
RewriteRule ^.*$ /categories/cat1$0 [R]
```

Or, do 301 redirection

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} cat1.my.site
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://my.site/categories/cat1$0 [R,L]
```

(Above code is untested so you might want to compare them with doc and test)

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html