# PHP function to get the subdomain of a URL

Tags: php, subdomain

Is there a function in PHP to get the name of the subdomain?

In the following example I would like to get the "en" part of the URL:

```
en.example.com
```

Comment: Do you have an URL as string stored in a variable or where is this URL coming from? What is the context? Please elaborate.

Comment: Couldn't you use a regex that did something like `(^|://)(.*)\.` and capture the `.*`? I rather suck at both php and regex, but this comes to mind.

Comment: What should it get in `en.foo.bar.example.com` or `en.example.co.uk`?

Comment: parse_url can also help

Answer (score 148):

Here's a one line solution:

```
array_shift((explode('.', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])));
```

Or using your example:

```
array_shift((explode('.', 'en.example.com')));
```

*EDIT: Fixed "only variables should be passed by reference" by adding double parenthesis.*

*EDIT 2*: Starting from [PHP 5.4](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php) you can simply do:

```
explode('.', 'en.example.com')[0];
```

Comment: Only variables should be passed by reference.

Comment: Aren't you able to just do `explode(...)[0]` instead of using shift these days? Not been PHPing for several years..

Comment: Error: `Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference.`

Comment: @Tor: As late as 5.3, no.  PHP's parser has always been particularly crappy in regards to stuff like that.  Looks like it was semi fixed in 5.4.

Comment: pretty sure you can (explode(...))[0] though, should be operating on the return array instead of the function paranthesis (prior to 5.4)

Comment: Another one, for the *one-liner string folks*: `$sub = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 0, strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], "."));`

Comment: It's not good solution, because about `example.com` domain, return `example` as the subdomain! you know in this case don't have subdomain.

Comment: @NabiK.A.Z. Easy enough to check for: `if(count(explode(".", $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])) === 3)`...

Comment: To solve the problem "Only variables should be passed by reference" do: `$arrayHost = explode('.', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']); echo array_shift($arrayHost);`

Comment: This solution will not work in case someone types in `www.en.example.com` and thus will return `www` as subdomain.

Comment: @lolbas, correct. I used... `echo array_shift((explode('.', str_replace("www.", "", $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']))));`

Answer (score 68):

Uses the [parse_url](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function.

```
$url = 'http://en.example.com';

$parsedUrl = parse_url($url);

$host = explode('.', $parsedUrl['host']);

$subdomain = $host[0];
echo $subdomain;
```

**For multiple subdomains**

```
$url = 'http://usa.en.example.com';

$parsedUrl = parse_url($url);

$host = explode('.', $parsedUrl['host']);

$subdomains = array_slice($host, 0, count($host) - 2 );
print_r($subdomains);
```

Comment: @Mike Lewis - Does this solve the problem of multiple subdomains, such as usa.en.example.com? Just wondering (my own answer doesn't, btw).

Comment: @Jared, just added a solution to detect multiple subdomains.

Comment: @Mike - Will that work with tx.usa.en.example.com? (or http://science.news.bbc.co.uk/)? (btw, that's not a working link, just an example, although news.bbc.co.uk does work)

Comment: That works for everything that has a single 'word' TLD like net, com, biz etc. However when dealing with co.uk, for example, it does not. As seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/288810/get-the-subdomain-from-a-url) This is actually a harder problem to solve.

Comment: That's true. Nice link. Just wondering, why not use `strrpos()` and an offset?

Comment: this also fails if there is no subdomain at all.

Comment: What about https://example.co.uk?

Answer (score 40):

You can do this by first getting the domain name (e.g. sub.example.com => example.co.uk) and then use strstr to get the subdomains.

```
$testArray = array(
    'sub1.sub2.example.co.uk',
    'sub1.example.com',
    'example.com',
    'sub1.sub2.sub3.example.co.uk',
    'sub1.sub2.sub3.example.com',
    'sub1.sub2.example.com'
);

foreach($testArray as $k => $v)
{
    echo $k." => ".extract_subdomains($v)."\n";
}

function extract_domain($domain)
{
    if(preg_match("/(?P<domain>[a-z0-9][a-z0-9\-]{1,63}\.[a-z\.]{2,6})$/i", $domain, $matches))
    {
        return $matches['domain'];
    } else {
        return $domain;
    }
}

function extract_subdomains($domain)
{
    $subdomains = $domain;
    $domain = extract_domain($subdomains);

    $subdomains = rtrim(strstr($subdomains, $domain, true), '.');

    return $subdomains;
}
```

Outputs:

```
0 => sub1.sub2
1 => sub1
2 =>
3 => sub1.sub2.sub3
4 => sub1.sub2.sub3
5 => sub1.sub2
```

Comment: This seems the best solution as it also allows for domains without a subdomain, rather than retruning the domain name as the subdomain being the part before the first dot.  Very useful for checking the existence of a subdomain.

Comment: I needed to get the "base" domain (without the subdomain), and I was making my own solution by exploding the host and getting the last elements of the array with a `for` loop, but I had to check their length (to detect if they were a part of the domain like the "co.uk"). Actually, your solution is far more simple than what I was doing. Regex save lives, thanks!

Comment: Awesome.. this works so well for all domain types and subdomains.. nice.

Comment: while this solution is very neat and may work in *almost* all cases, be aware that domains names might have more than 6 chars, like `pvt.k12.ma.us`, `health.vn` or even `k12.ak.us`. Also, domains names may be use Chinese or Russian character set so the regex part `[a-z\.]{2,6}` would not match them. Check out here to have example domains name: https://publicsuffix.org/list/

Answer (score 13):

http://php.net/parse_url

```
<?php
  $url = 'http://user:password@sub.hostname.tld/path?argument=value#anchor';
  $array=parse_url($url);
  $array['host']=explode('.', $array['host']);

  echo $array['host'][0]; // returns 'sub'
?>
```

Answer (score 9):

As the only reliable source for domain suffixes are the domain registrars, you can't find the subdomain without their knowledge.
There is a list with all domain suffixes at https://publicsuffix.org. This site also links to a PHP library: https://github.com/jeremykendall/php-domain-parser.

Please find an example below. I also added the sample for en.test.co.uk which is a domain with a multi suffix (co.uk).

```
<?php

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

$pslManager = new Pdp\PublicSuffixListManager();
$parser = new Pdp\Parser($pslManager->getList());
$host = 'http://en.example.com';
$url = $parser->parseUrl($host);

echo $url->host->subdomain;


$host = 'http://en.test.co.uk';
$url = $parser->parseUrl($host);

echo $url->host->subdomain;
```

Answer (score 7):

PHP 7.0: Use the explode function and create a list of all the results.

```
list($subdomain,$host) = explode('.', $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]);
```

***Example: sub.domain.com***

```
echo $subdomain;
```

**Result:** sub

```
echo $host;
```

**Result:** domain

Comment: You forget TLD's like `.co.uk` - your snippet will not work with these TLDs

Comment: This is the best answer for modern PHP.

Answer (score 6):

## **Simply...**

```
    preg_match('/(?:http[s]*\:\/\/)*(.*?)\.(?=[^\/]*\..{2,5})/i', $url, $match);
```

Just read *$match[1]*

## **Working example**

It works perfectly with this list of urls

```
$url = array(
    'http://www.domain.com', // www
    'http://domain.com', // --nothing--
    'https://domain.com', // --nothing--
    'www.domain.com', // www
    'domain.com', // --nothing--
    'www.domain.com/some/path', // www
    'http://sub.domain.com/domain.com', // sub
    'опубликованному.значения.ua', // опубликованному ;)
    'значения.ua', // --nothing--
    'http://sub-domain.domain.net/domain.net', // sub-domain
    'sub-domain.third-Level_DomaIN.domain.uk.co/domain.net' // sub-domain
);

foreach ($url as $u) {
    preg_match('/(?:http[s]*\:\/\/)*(.*?)\.(?=[^\/]*\..{2,5})/i', $u, $match);
    var_dump($match);
}
```

Comment: PS - I don't have any idea of what it's written in the russian text. Just took some casual words from *ru.wikipedia.org* ;)

Comment: Isn't it Ukrainian? `.ua` is the country code for Ukraine.

Comment: Nope. Just mixed information. But I'm not sure, I'm not good enough to distinguish them ;)

Comment: In regards to the russian, a google translate from Russian to English comes back as "published values" (in case anyone was curious like I was)

Comment: @Kamafeather this looks bulletproof. Any way to just get the `$match[1]` part? `$match[0]` seems unnecessary.

Comment: I am not sure to understand what you mean/need. From [*preg_match* PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php): *"`$matches[0]` will contain the text that matched the full pattern, `$matches[1]` will have the text that matched the first captured parenthesized subpattern, and so on."* I don't think you can't get rid of `match[0]`, it is always there, because of how `preg_match` is implemented. You can eventually `array_shift` it, if you don't want to have it in the array.

Answer (score 5):

Simplest and fastest solution.

```
$sSubDomain = str_replace('.example.com','',$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$REFERRER = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; // Or other method to get a URL for decomposition

$domain = substr($REFERRER, strpos($REFERRER, '://')+3);
$domain = substr($domain, 0, strpos($domain, '/'));
// This line will return 'en' of 'en.example.com'
$subdomain = substr($domain, 0, strpos($domain, '.'));
```

Comment: There are better ways to auto detect the current host (like `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`) then relying on a spoof-able referrer header, assuming that's what the general idea behind the answer is.

Comment: Right, I was using an old piece of code. The example still stands, however. That's not the root of the question.

Comment: Just to add up on these comments above, relying on $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] may not be effiicient, since there's a chance it may not be set.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't really a 100% dynamic solution - I've just been trying to figure it out as well and due to different domain extensions (DTL) this task would be really difficult without actually parsing all these extensions and checking them each time:

`.com vs .co.uk vs org.uk`

The most reliable option is to define a constant (or database entry etc.) that stores the actual domain name and remove it from the `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` using `substr()`

```
defined("DOMAIN")
    || define("DOMAIN", 'mymaindomain.co.uk');



function getSubDomain() {

    if (empty($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])) {

        return null;

    }

    $subDomain = substr($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], 0, -(strlen(DOMAIN)));

    if (empty($subDomain)) {

        return null;

    }

    return rtrim($subDomain, '.');

}
```

Now if you're using this function under `http://test.mymaindomain.co.uk` it will give you `test` or if you have multiple sub-domain levels `http://another.test.mymaindomain.co.uk` you'll get `another.test` - unless of course you update the `DOMAIN`.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Using regex, string functions, parse_url() or their combinations it's not real solution. Just test any of proposed solutions with domain `test.en.example.co.uk`, there will no any correct result.

Correct solution is use package that parses domain with [Public Suffix List](https://publicsuffix.org/). I recomend [TLDExtract](https://github.com/layershifter/TLDExtract), here is sample code:

```
$extract = new LayerShifter\TLDExtract\Extract();

$result = $extract->parse('test.en.example.co.uk');
$result->getSubdomain(); // will return (string) 'test.en'
$result->getSubdomains(); // will return (array) ['test', 'en']
$result->getHostname(); // will return (string) 'example'
$result->getSuffix(); // will return (string) 'co.uk'
```

Answer (score 1):

What I found the best and short solution is

```
array_shift(explode(".",$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']));
```

Comment: Will cause Strict error. Output of explode can not be passed directly to array_shift.

Answer (score 1):

For those who get 'Error: Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference.'
Use like this:

`$env = (explode(".",$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']));
$env = array_shift($env);`

Comment: That was not the question, but thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

```
$domain = 'sub.dev.example.com';
$tmp = explode('.', $domain); // split into parts
$subdomain = current($tmp);
print($subdomain);     // prints "sub"
```

As seen in a previous question:
[How to get the first subdomain with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13832626/how-to-get-the-first-subdomain-with-php)

Answer (score 1):

Simply

`reset(explode(".", $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']))`

Answer (score 1):

this is my solution, it works with the most common domains, you can fit the array of extensions as you need:

```
$SubDomain = explode('.', explode('|ext|', str_replace(array('.com', '.net', '.org'), '|ext|',$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']))[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing something like this

```
$url = https://en.example.com

$splitedBySlash = explode('/', $url);
$splitedByDot = explode('.', $splitedBySlash[2]);

$subdomain = $splitedByDot[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose current url = *sub.example.com*

```
    $host = array_reverse(explode('.', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']));

    if (count($host) >= 3){
       echo "Main domain is = ".$host[1].".".$host[0]." & subdomain is = ".$host[2];
       // Main domain is = example.com & subdomain is = sub
    } else {
       echo "Main domain is = ".$host[1].".".$host[0]." & subdomain not found";
       // "Main domain is = example.com & subdomain not found";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// For www.abc.en.example.com 
$host_Array = explode(".",$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']); // Get HOST as array www, abc, en, example, com
array_pop($host_Array); array_pop($host_Array);   // Remove com and exmaple
array_shift($host_Array);                         // Remove www (Optional)
echo implode($host_Array, ".");                   // Combine array abc.en
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm really late to the game, but here goes.

What I did was take the HTTP_HOST server variable (`$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`) and the number of letters in the domain (so for `example.com` it would be 11).

Then I used the `substr` function to get the subdomain. I did

```
$numberOfLettersInSubdomain = strlen($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])-12
$subdomain = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], $numberOfLettersInSubdomain);
```

I cut the substring off at 12 instead of 11 because substrings start on 1 for the second parameter. So now if you entered test.example.com, the value of `$subdomain` would be `test`.

This is better than using `explode` because if the subdomain has a `.` in it, this will not cut it off.

Comment: The start position "0" was missing in your answer.

$subdomain = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 0, $numberOfLettersInSubdomain);

Answer (score 0):

if you are using drupal 7

this will help you:

```
global $base_path;
global $base_root;  
$fulldomain = parse_url($base_root);    
$splitdomain = explode(".", $fulldomain['host']);
$subdomain = $splitdomain[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
preg_match("/[^\.\/]+\.[^\.\/]+$/", $host, $matches);
$domain = $matches[0];
$url = explode($domain, $host);
$subdomain = str_replace('.', '', $url[0]);

echo 'subdomain: '.$subdomain.'<br />';
echo 'domain: '.$domain.'<br />';
```

Answer (score 0):

From PHP 5.3 you can use **strstr()** with **true** parameter

```
echo strstr($_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"], '.', true); //prints en
```

Comment: This will only work if there is no `www` at string start. A bit too trivial approach.

Comment: This simplify things for other developers in the team, I'd rather use this than some advanced reg exp. If you want to trim www use trim($s,'www'); or just adjust it to your business logic...

Comment: For completeness sake, `www` *is* actually a subdomain. It's just commonly aliased to the domain name itself for historical reasons.

Answer (score 0):

```
function get_subdomain($url=""){
    if($url==""){
        $url = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    }
    $parsedUrl = parse_url($url);
    $host = explode('.', $parsedUrl['path']);
    $subdomains = array_slice($host, 0, count($host) - 2 );
    return implode(".", $subdomains);
}
```

Comment: line #7 should be `$host = explode('.', isset($parsedUrl['path']) ? $parsedUrl['path'] : $parsedUrl['host']);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
$domain = 'en.example.com';
$tmp = explode('.', $domain);
$subdomain = current($tmp);
echo($subdomain);     // echo "en"
```

Comment: I think it would be more helpful for the OP and further visitors, when you add some explaination to youer intension.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this too

```
echo substr($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 0, strrpos($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], '.', -5));
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm late, but even though the post is old, just as I get to it, many others do.

Today, the wheel is already invented, with a library called [php-domain-parser](https://github.com/jeremykendall/php-domain-parser) that is active, and in which two mechanisms can be used.
One based on the [Public Suffix List](https://publicsuffix.org/list/public_suffix_list.dat) and one based on the [IANA list](https://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt).

Simple and effective, it allows us to create simple helpers that help us in our project, with the ability to know that the data is maintained, in a world in which the extensions and their variants are very changeable.

Many of the answers given in this post do not pass a battery of unit tests, in which certain current extensions and their variants with multiple levels are checked, and neither with the casuistry of domains with extended characters.

Maybe it serves you, as it served me.

Answer (score 0):

```
$parts = explode('.', $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]);
$subdomain = count($parts) < 3 ? null : $parts[0];
```

Answer (score -5):

If you only want what comes before the first period:

```
list($sub) = explode('.', 'en.example.com', 2);
```

Comment: What if there is a protocol handler at the beginning, such as http://, https://, ftp://, etc...? ;)

Comment: @Jared, there's no protocol in the string he's looking to parse... But if there were, I'd use `parse_url()` to extract the host.

Comment: So we've provided two approaches which will be appropriate in different contexts.

Comment: Mainly, I'm just glad someone hasn't posted a regex answer (yet). Not to mention the last line of my answer also accomplishes the same thing yours does.

Comment: And if the hostname is en.example.co.uk?

Comment: @Marc B - See my comments on Mike Lewis' answer.