# get subdomain in php

Tags: php, zend-framework, url

I have following urls.

```
reservation.abchotel.com
booking.abchotels.org
abc1.abc.dev
```

I want to get sub domain from above urls.

ex:-

```
.abchotel.com
.abchotels.org
.abc.dev
```

How I do it? I'm using zend feamwork. Please help me. What is the best solution?

Comment: in your exemple, you don't get the subdomains, but the domains. the sub domaines are "reservation","booking"... or did you mean "strip" instead of "get" ?

Comment: and what do you want to do with your domain or sub-domains? the answer could depend on it

Comment: thanks Frederik. I use this cord for add my google analytic code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they are always in that form you could do something like the following (assuming `$url` is set).

```
$split_url = explode(".", $url);
$subdomain = ".".$split_url[1].".".$split_url[2];
```

Or did you want to know how to get the URL in the first place too, or to allow for more than 3-level domains?

Comment: is there no way to handle other forms?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you don't want the subdomain but the domain. Because what you listed are not the subdomains.

The following pieces of knowledge will enable you to successfully deal with domain names.

- [Zend_Validate_Hostname](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.validate.set.html#zend.validate.set.hostname) - also good to look at the code
- [PHP Server variables](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)
- String manipulation in general. Hostnames are easy to in- and explode since they're always delimited by dots.
- [PHP parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

See also[this question on SO on how to [get subdomain(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292937/php-function-to-get-the-subdomain-of-a-url) from an url.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple way to get domain and subdomain :

```
$parts = explode('.', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);

$domain = '.' . implode( '.', array_reverse( 
              array(
                 array_pop($parts),
                 array_pop($parts)
              )
          );
$subdomain = implode('.',$parts);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"];
$replace_domains = array(
  ".abchotel.com" => "",
  ".abchotels.org" => "",
  ".abc.dev" => "");

$url = str_replace(array_keys($replace_domains), array_values($replace_domains), $url);

echo $url;
```

Comment: Looking at the other answers, it looks like you don't want the subdomain, but the domain. It's <subdomain>.<domain>.<tld>