# Detect if a user is on a subdomain, and then add a variable using PHP?

Tags: php, variables, subdomain, detection

I would like to know how to create a PHP IF Statement that detects if a user is loading/on a certain URL. In my case it's:

```
www.design.mywebsite.com
```

The IF Statement needs to cover the whole subdomain, EG the URL will also have to be detected:

```
www.design.mywebsite.com/filename.php
```

Once an IF statement is established, I want to add a PHP variable. So it might help others, let's call it:

```
$myvariable = "Hey there! You're on my subdomain";
```

**So To Sum It Up:**
The final code should look something like this...

```
<?php
  if //Code to detect subdomain// {
    $myvariable = "Hey there! You're on my subdomain";
  }
?>
```

Comment: This has already been asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292937/php-function-to-get-the-subdomain-of-a-url

Comment: Hi there dragon112.

I have already looked at that, and yes I was aware of it - but I'm a bit confused as to how I would turn it into a PHP IF Statement.

Comment: Thanks for commenting so quickly ogur :).

I know that it will require a parse_url(), but I'm not sure where to go from there.

Comment: Well I guess you have to check if array returned from parse_url() (or exploded parts of that array) contains subdomain name you look for, am I right?

Comment: I think that would have a fair chance at working. Do you reckon you can show me how it's done though as an answer? Cheers.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A simple solution is

```
$host = "baba.stackoverflow.com"; // Your Sub domain

if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == $host) {
    echo "Hello baba Sub Domain";
} else {
    echo "not baba domain";
}
```

You can also use  `parse_url` http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php if you have the `URL`

```
$url = "http://baba.stackoverflow.com/questions/10171866/detect-if-a-user-is-on-a-subdomain-and-then-add-a-variable-using-php";
$info = parse_url($url);
if ($info['host'] == $host) {
    echo "Hello baba Sub Domain";
} else {
    echo "not baba domain";
}
```

Please replace `$url` with `$_GET` ;

Comment: Outstanding answer - couldn't have asked for better. Worked like a charm. Thank you very much Baba.