# PHP - Efficient way to check if subdomain exists

Tags: php, url, subdomain

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP function to get the subdomain of a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292937/php-function-to-get-the-subdomain-of-a-url)

Im looking for an efficient way to tell if a subdomain exists within a URL.

The domain name will always be fixed e.g. mydomin.com, however if a subdomain is not set, I need to redirect.

One thought I had is that if there is more than one period (.), a subdomain is set, but im not sure how to implement this.

Many thanks.

**EDIT:** Sorry for not being too clear. I do not have a current solution, but looking at other posts I can see several examples of how to get the subdomain e.g.

```
array_shift(explode(".",$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']));
```

But i do not want the subdomain, just to check if one exists. The subdomain could be anything.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292937/php-function-to-get-the-subdomain-of-a-url

Comment: Do you already have an **inefficient** solution? Usually programmers ask about something efficient when their current solution just doesn't fit the performance requirements. So, what's your *current* one?

Comment: How are you doing it currently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the hostname with `parse_url`. Then you break it down with `explode()`:

```
function hasSubdomain($url) {
    $parsed = parse_url($url);
    $exploded = explode('.', $parsed["host"]);
    return (count($exploded) > 2);
}
```

On google you can find really easily how to redirect someone.

Comment: What about `"someDomainName.co.uk"`? I wouldn't say that has a subdomain. But that would return `true` for this function no?

Comment: Just check if count() is higher than 3, instead of 2.

Comment: I guess this is the better answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/288864/839332 But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I would rather use apache rewrite engine (or any webserver rewrite process) :

```
# .htaccess file

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yourdomin\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://sub.yourdomin.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```