# How to get the first subdomain with PHP?

Tags: php, subdomain

I have a static domain of `dev.example.com` with wildcard subdomains like so `*.dev.example.com`.

I need to detect the name of the current wildcard subdomain. So if I'm browsing `sub.dev.example.com` how do I get "sub"?

```
$env_domain = dev.example.com;
$subdomain = array_shift( explode( '.', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ) ) .'.'. $env_domain;
echo $subdomain;
```

Currently, this returns `dev`. I need it to return `sub`.

I'm thinking the best practice here would be to return the most low-level domain (the first subdomain).

Note that I'm not parsing a URL, but a given domain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$domain = 'sub.dev.example.com';
$tmp = explode('.', $domain);
$subdomain = current($tmp);
print($subdomain);     // prints "sub"
```

Answer (score 3):

This is another simple solution for the question.

```
echo array_shift((explode(".",$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])));
```

Answer (score 2):

I think using [parse_url](https://www.php.net/parse_url) function is  much better approach:

```
getUrlSubdomain($url){
    $urlSegments = parse_url($url);
    $urlHostSegments = explode('.', $urlSegments['host']);

    if(count($urlHostSegments) > 2) {
        return $urlHostSegments[0];
    }
    else{
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a little function that'll do the trick.
Just stick $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] into the function and you should get what you want

```
function getSubDomain ($domain) {
    $eDom = explode('.', $domain);
    return $eDom[0];
}

echo getSubDomain('sub.dev.example.com'); // echo 'sub'
```

Answer (score 0):

From PHP 5.3 you can use strstr() with true parameter

```
echo strstr('sub.dev.example.com', '.', true); //prints sub
```

[Original link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24788942/949273)