# PHP Get Subdomain But Not Actual Domain

Tags: php, subdomain

I'm currently using the following to get the subdomain of my site

```
$subdomain = array_shift(explode(".",$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']));
```

When I use this for http://www.website.com it returns "www" which is expected

However when I use this with http://website.com it returns "website" as the subdomain. How can I make absolute sure that if there is no subdomain as in that example, it returns NULL?

Thanks!

Comment: what does $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] give you ?

Comment: Possibly to duplity content http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292937/php-function-to-get-the-subdomain-of-a-url
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13832626/how-to-get-the-first-subdomain-with-php

Comment: I checked out that post, it's a bit different as I want to return null if the subdomain is not present.. while that returns the domain as the sub.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, note that in common case you should first apply parse_url to incoming data - and then use [host] key from it. As for your question, you can use something like this:

```
preg_match('/([^\.]+)\.[^\.]+\.[^\.]+$/', 'www.domain.com', $rgMatches);
//2-nd level check:
//preg_match('/([^\.]+)\.[^\.]+\.[^\.]+$/', 'domain.com', $rgMatches);
$sDomain = count($rgMatches)?$rgMatches[1]:null;
```

But I'm not sure that it's exactly what you need (since url can contain 4-th domain level e t.c.)

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
function getSubdomain($domain) {
    $expl = explode(".", $domain, -2);
    $sub = "";
    if(count($expl) > 0) {
        foreach($expl as $key => $value) {
            $sub = $sub.".".$value;

        }
        $sub = substr($sub, 1);
    }
    return $sub;
}
$subdomain = getSubdomain($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
```

Works fine for me. Basicly you need to use the explode limit parameter. 
Detail and source: [phph.net - explode manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Answer (score 0):

If you have other domain, like a `.net` or `.org` etc, just change the value accordingly

```
$site['uri'] = explode(".", str_replace('.com', '', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) );
if( count($site['uri']) >0 ) {
    $site['subdomain'] = $site['uri'][0];
    $site['domain'] = $site['uri'][1];
    }
else  { 
    $site['subdomain'] = null;
    $site['domain'] = $site['uri'][0];
}
//For testing only:
print_r($site);
```

...or not (for more flexibility):

```
$site['uri'] = explode(".", $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] );
if( count($site['uri']) > 2 ) {
    $site['subdomain'] = $site['uri'][0];
    $site['domain'] = $site['uri'][1];
    }
else  { 
    $site['subdomain'] = null;
    $site['domain'] = $site['uri'][0];
}
//For testing only:
print_r($site);
```