# Reading URL in php

Tags: php, url

I want to check the request is come from which URL LIKE     ---  `www.mysite.com or bussiness.mysite.com` .How can we check it,as $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] gives whole URL . 
Thanks .

Comment: then what is the problem ?

Comment: use a regex to match and extract?

Comment: If `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` contains a URL then there is some serious problem with your clients / proxies setup! php's documentation clearly states that the value of that field is the content of the http `Host:` header. If a client puts a url in there is _really_ is broken! What does `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME]` contain?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292937/php-function-to-get-the-subdomain-of-a-url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing you want is Subdomain of your url. Use this

```
$subdomain =  array_shift(explode(".",$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']));
```

Comment: I'd put a thought into this question first: why is there such strange / invalid content in there?

Comment: Invalid content in the sense?

Comment: $_REQUEST['HTTP_HOST'] should not contain a URL but the content of the requests `Host:` header. If it suddenly contains a url then something is _really_ borked in the setup, most likely on client or proxy side. So what you do is trying to cure a symptom instead of the cause.

Answer (score 1):

```
$domain = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$path = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
$queryString = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
$url = "http://" . $domain . $path . "?" . $queryString;
echo "The current URL is: " . $url . "";

visit :http://www.2basetechnologies.com/
```

Comment: i want sub domain not a whole url .