# How to auto generate a random unique permanent secure ID based on current url, store it automatically inside database and display it in php page?

Tags: php, mysql

I need help to auto generate a random unique permanent secure ID based on current url, store it automatically inside database and display it in php page ?

I have a multisite and everytime someone create a new subdomain I like to display
on the page a unique secure id based on current new subdomain and display it in his
page like :

**ID PAGE SECURE NUMBER**: `6465465DSGDGDGDG4564EEEZ7778`

Answer (score 1):

PHP has a hashing function you could use. I would also add a random salt to it, can be anything really like a string of text or numbers

```
$url = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; 
$salt = "i.am.a.rand0m.str1ng.Of.ChArAcT3r$";
echo hash('sha1', $url . $salt);
```

There are other hashes you could use: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php

There is also the [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function of PHP, but this requires 5.5.0 or greater.

*edit* swapped out the URL for $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], though there are probably better ways of getting the current URL.

Comment: I need help to auto generate a random unique permanent secure ID based on current url not a fixed url

Comment: Google was just an example, you can substitute that using something like $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']. I'll update my example with that

Comment: I just did it but the number don't change when I change url

Comment: So what you suggest ? for the moment your solution not working

Comment: Ah http_host may not be picking up the subdomain and treating it just as your main domain. I think you'll need to find a way to grab the sudomain URL, maybe [one of these](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292937/php-function-to-get-the-subdomain-of-a-url) solutions can help?

Comment: I find a a way to grab subfolder and it work. Now how to store it in database?

Comment: Do you have a database set up where you can store the details? What have you tried so far with inserting the data? If you haven't already looked, read up on using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). There are loads of posts on stack (and around the net) for inserting data. Have a search for PDO PHP MySQL. I would adivse against using mysql_* queries as they have been deprecated now. Some more info to read over - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php/60496#60496

Answer (score 0):

create an table tab1 with pagename,randomnum

```
<?php
$myurl = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

$q1=mysql_query("select * from tab1 where pagename='$myurl' ");
$c=mysql_num_rows();
$row=mysql_fetch_array($q1);
if($c>0)
{
 $url=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']."?secureid=$row['randomnum']";
    header( "Location: $url" );
}
else
{
$chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
$rand = substr( str_shuffle( $chars ), 0,8 );
$q2=mysql_query("insert into tab1 (pagename,randomnum) values ('$myurl','$rand')");
}
?>
```

Comment: mysql_ is deprecated. do not use/recommend it

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by "create an table tab1 with pagename,randomnum" ? I just cut and past the two code above in the same php page and it's not working..

Comment: Dreamweaver said there is an error here:     $url=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']."?secureid=$row['randomnum']";

Comment: I paste this on the top: <?php
$myurl =  basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
 $q1=mysql_query("select * from tab1 where pagename='$myurl' ");
$row=mysql_fetch_array($q1);
    $c=mysql_num_rows();
    if($c>0)
    {
    $url=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']."?secureid=$row['randomnum']";
    header( "Location: $url" );
    }
?>

Comment: and this in the middle: <?php
$myurl = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

$q1=mysql_query("select * from tab1 where pagename='$myurl' ");
$c=mysql_num_rows();
if($c>0)
{

}
else
{
$chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
$rand = substr( str_shuffle( $chars ), 0,8 );
$q2=mysql_query("insert into tab1 (pagename,randomnum) values ('$myurl','$rand')");
}
?>

Comment: So what you suggest ? for the moment your solution not working