# Get subdomain as a GET parameter

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Basically I have this htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([a-z0-9-]+).([a-z0-9-]+)([/admin])? [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ index.php?domainusr=%1 [L]
```

Imagine that the subdomain will be a User, and I want to get that user. But the thing is this htaccess will work, with some drawbacks:

- If I access something like: "http://username.domain.com/" it will work.
- If I access "http://username.domain.com/index.php" it will not.
- If I access any other urls than "http://username.domain.com/", like: "http://username.domain.com/admin/", "http://username.domain.com/front/index.php", it won't work.

My question is: How can I have this subdomain as a GET parameter in EVERY accessable content, without interfering with others GETs?

Comment: Not a solution but a proposal: why not using something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292937/php-function-to-get-the-subdomain-of-a-url#answer-11127956) to get the subdomain instead of adding a GET parameter?

Comment: It will indeed work, but I really wanted to see a solution using mod-rewrite. But thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to add `?domainusr=%1` to all your links, with this `.htaccess`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([a-z0-9-]+)\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1?domainusr=%1 [QSA,L]
```