# PHP Header Redirect not working when used with "www"

Tags: php

I'm using this but whenever i try to open with www, it gives me an error:

```
if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == "sub.mydomain.com")
header("Location: mydomain.com/sub/");
```

Where am I going wrong?

I want users redirected when they type sub.mydomain.com or www.sub.mydomain.com

Comment: `if (strpos('sub.mydomain.com', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) !== false)`

Comment: What error? The Location: header is supposed to carry an URL (that includes `http://`), not an browser address bar string.

Comment: Do this on a higher level with apache or nginx. You can wildcard your subdomain and have the web server redirect all requests to root.

Comment: @davidxd33 That is only possible if op has access to the server. he/she may not have that!

Comment: i coulnd't include http:// while posting and so removed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do a correct header call.

Like this:

```
if(strpos('sub.example.com', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) !== false){
    header("location: http://example.com/sub/");
}
```

**EDIT:** 
Based on the information in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25236928/1833314) post: 
You can also use this function instead:

```
function get_subdomain($url=""){
    if($url==""){
        $url = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    }
    $parsedUrl = parse_url($url);
    $host = explode('.', $parsedUrl['path']);
    $subdomains = array_slice($host, 0, count($host) - 2 );
    return implode(".", $subdomains);
}

if('sub' != get_subdomain()){
      header("location: http://example.com/sub/");
}
```

Comment: I tried this and the website went down! :(

And why would anyone give a negative rating?!! I coulnd't find any online tutorial and hence posted here

Comment: This is the way to do it, Then you probably have an error in your code somewhare

Comment: I just copied pasted it and changed the domain name. Twice!! I'll look into it again shortly after dinner. Thank You :)

Comment: You could try this edited code. If it doesn't work there probably is some other error in your code!

Comment: I have tried both of these examples and they ARE working. So as i've said earlier, your problem derives from somewhere else!

Comment: The main problem was that i didn't create another subdomain with www. I'm using aws amazon. Thank you so much :)