# PHP filter links

Tags: php

i have this array

```
    $array = array(
        "http://www.mywebsite.com/eternal_link_1",
        "http://www.mywebsite.com/eternal_link_2/",
        "http://www.mywebsite.com/eternal_link_1/#",
        "http://subdomain1.mywebwite.com",
        "http://subdomain2.mywebwite.com/eternal_link",
        "http://www.external-link.com"
    );

    $eternal_links = array();
    $subdomain_links = array();
    $external_links = array();
```

how i can filter $array and add the values to the 3 arrays above?

Comment: You need to provide more information about what you hope to filter _by_. Consider what the actual distinguishing features of each type of link is, otherwise there's no way to know where to put each link.

Comment: there is 3 arrays, for eternal links, external links and subdomain

Comment: If you think they are eternal, you are mistaken.

Comment: sorry i will change the links to be more clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `strpos` to find the correct string.

```
foreach($array as $item){

   if(strpos($item, 'external') == TRUE){
      array_push($external_links, $item);
   }

   // and go on..
}
```

Comment: it's just example links, there is no 'external' word in the links

Comment: @dev.bashar yes, that's taken, so adapt the example code provided to your own situation. This is an example you can use to reach the solution you want. Adapt its details .

Comment: Ohh, sorry for that. But, to know which ones are from a subdomain, you need to check for the domain..and you have the name of the domain or not?

Comment: no i don't have the links, there is page php function read the links from html pages and i want to filter the results to this 3 arrays

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292937/php-function-to-get-the-subdomain-of-a-url you can get if it's a subdomain or not from there.