# Symfony2 DI service container priority/flow

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection, request

**The story**

Let's take this request `https://nike.awesomedomainname.com/` as an example. I need a service that can fetch the `nike`.

---

**What I currently have**

I've a service that fetches a router key from the `@request_stack`. Let's use company as router key.

My main route as followed;

```
<import host="{company}.domain.{_tld}" prefix="/" schemes="https" resource="@ExampleBundle/Resources/config/routing.xml">
    <default key="_tld">%app_tld%</default>
    <requirement key="_tld">com|dev</requirement>
    <requirement key="company">[a-z0-9]+</requirement>
</import>
```

So I wrote this service to fetch the key and search for the company;

```
...

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;

class CompanyContextRequest {

    protected $request;
    protected $companyRepository;

    public function __construct(RequestStack $requestStack, CompanyRepository $companyRepository) {
        $this->request = $requestStack->getMasterRequest();
        $this->companyRepository = $companyRepository;
    }

    public function getCompany()
    {
        if (null !== $this->request)
        {
            $company = $this->request->attributes->get('company');
            if (null !== $company)
            {
                return $this->companyRepository->findOneBy([
                    'key' => $company
                ]);
            }
        }
    }

    ....

}
```

And the service xml definition;

```
<service id="app.company_context_request" class="AppBundle\Request\CompanyContextRequest">
    <argument type="service" id="request_stack"/>
    <argument type="service" id="orm_entity.company_repository"/>
</service>
<service id="app.current_company" class="AppBundle\Entity\Company">
    <factory service="app.company_context_request" method="getCompany"/>
</service>
```

Now my problem is that in some cases the service `app.current_company` doesn't return a `Company` object instead a `null` is given.

For example I have a custom `UserProvider` that has the `CompanyContextRequest` as a dependency to check if the user belongs to the company but I can't do so because it returns `null`.

But it works perfectly in controllers and most other DI places.

Any suggestions? Is there something like priority for services like for event subscribers?

---

**What I've tried**

I've set the scope `app.company_context_request` into `request` and tried to fetch it from the container. With false results.
According to the Symfony docs this should work.

---

I run the latest stable version of Symfony v2.7.3

---

**Edit**: My goal is to have a service at all times that can tell me the current company that is based ofcourse on the subdomain.

**Edit 2**: [This example](http://brentertainment.com/2012/02/28/contextualizing-your-symfony2-application-with-the-service-container/) is almost what I need except that in this example they use the users company and I need the company(key) from the subdomain.

Comment: Don't you need instead to create a dependency between UserProvider and app.current_company which would be the current company according to the request, and then check if your user is linked to the current company ? Also, did you check if, while being in your USerProvider business logic, you had the right parameters (e.g. company and tld) in your request ?

Comment: @MeuhMeuh that is what I'm doing with `app.current_company` is an instance of Company entity. But since the container is compiled before the request is made the `company` attribute in the current request is `null`. That's why I need an solution regarding my dependency on the request.

Comment: when does it return null?

Comment: Isn't it a scope problem ? Did-you try :
    <service id="app.company_context_request" class="AppBundle\Request\CompanyContextRequest" scope="request" >

Comment: Is your company is `NULL` when you call the service in a sub request by calling PHP or Twig `render(controller('FooBar'))` ?

Comment: @AndrewAtkinson when the `UserProvider` is called by the firewall.
@J-Mose No that didn't solve it and my other services would also required to be from the same scope `request` or an narrower scope or you'll get a `ScopeWideningException`.
@Divi calling the `app.current_company` in the controller/twig works.

Comment: have you try to debug the lifecycle of app.company_context_request service ? Try to find out (in case when you get null) where your class CompanyContextRequest access in that nested if conditions

Comment: @Vardius I did `dump` the masterRequest in the services constructor and received empty attributes, request and query.

Comment: So im pretty sure its the scope problem. As @J-Mose said it before.
You are invokeing your service before request is even ready. As symfony docs says `Outside the handling of a request, $requestStack->getCurrentRequest() returns null.` -> http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-4-the-request-stack

Comment: @Vardius that did sound completely logical indeed! As so I did change my service's scope into `request` leaving me also with a disappointing result: `null`. Any chance of a working example or another solution?

Answer (score 3):

The problem that your service `app.company_context_request` is **synthetic** by nature - you cannot compile cause there is no request data at this moment.

[How to Inject Instances into the Container](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/synthetic_services.html)

**Why does it work in some places?**

It works for cases when you call the services in the scope: after synthetic service `Request` was inserted into Service Container and scope `request` was activated. `request` scope setup and `RequestStack` filling happen into `\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareHttpKernel::handle` method and its parent one.

`UserProvider` doesn't work cause its initialization happens out of `request` scope: before `Request` service is activated or after the app left the scope.

**How to prevent it?**

1. Save `RequestStack` service to the service property and get current request not in the constructor but in the `getCompany` method - at the moment of calling constructor `Request` could be undefined;

   ```
   public function __construct(RequestStack $requestStack, CompanyRepository $companyRepository) 
   {
       // You cannot use request at this point cause at initialization of the service there could be no request yet
       $this->requestStack = $requestStack;
       $this->companyRepository = $companyRepository;
   }
   ...
   public function getCompany()
   {
       $request = $this->requestStack->getMasterRequest();
       if (null !== $request)
   ...
   ```
2. Add to service definition scope `request` and get it with via `container` inside another services: it will autogenerate exceptions when any services will try to get the one out of scope; There some constraints you should be aware: [How to Work with Scopes](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/scopes.html) This way is used in `FOS` bundles, for instance, `FOSOauthServer`.

If you will change code as in 1 then you can left service definition as it is

```
<service id="app.company_context_request" class="AppBundle\Request\CompanyContextRequest">
    <argument type="service" id="request_stack"/>
    <argument type="service" id="orm_entity.company_repository"/>
</service>
```

But `current_company` should have `scope`. `request` to throw exception if `Request` is not defined at the moment of initialization of the `current_company`. Or you can use `scope=prototype` (it will return new instance on every call) if you want to get `current_company` in the moments when it is set and get `null` in the moments when `Request` doens't exist (out of scope, cli calls).

```
<service id="app.current_company" class="AppBundle\Entity\Company" scope="request">
    <factory service="app.company_context_request" method="getCompany"/>
</service>
```

**UPD**
It is not related to service priorities at all. It is related with container compilation mechanism. Compilation of the certain service happens on first call of this service: on explicit call or on compilation of dependent service.

With `UserProvider` routes compilation of your service (so calling of the *__construct*) happens at the moment when `Request` object is not yet in `RequestStack` and in the `Container`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't really understand you question but if you want to set priority in YML is done like this

```
app.locale_listener:
    class: Erik\AppBundle\Service\LocateListener
    arguments: ["%kernel.default_locale%"]
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_subscriber, priority: 17 }
```

--- Edit ---

As first fix your ssl setup "This Connection is Untrusted" under linux firefox  there are online tools to check if ssl is configured correctly.

As second the answer to your question you can set up some service or event listener that will read subdomain name, in case of service just use $this->get("serviceName")->getSubdomain()

how to get subdomain [PHP function to get the subdomain of a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292937/php-function-to-get-the-subdomain-of-a-url)

Comment: I need a service to know the "current company" for ex: you go to `https://nike.superawesomedomain.com/` I want the subdomain name from the router so I can check it up against the database and return an `Company` (entity) object. So no events/listeners.