# Strip string containing URL to the domain, and include subdomain if available

Tags: php, url

Currently, I can strip the domain of the URL string by:

```
$pattern = '/\w+\..{2,3}(?:\..{2,3})?(?:$|(?=\/))/i';
$url = 'http://www.example.com/foo/bar?hat=bowler&accessory=cane';
if (preg_match($pattern, $url, $matches) === 1) {
    echo $matches[0];
}
```

This will echo:

```
example.com
```

The problem is that I want to include the subdomain **if it exists**.

So for example:

```
$url = 'http://sub.domain.example.com/foo/bar?hat=bowler&accessory=cane';
```

Should echo:

```
sub.domain.example.com
```

How can I achieve this insanity?

Comment: Try this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292937/php-function-to-get-the-subdomain-of-a-url

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [parse_url()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function for this:

```
$str = 'http://sub.domain.example.com/foo/bar?hat=bowler&accessory=cane';
$parts = parse_url($str);
print_r($parts);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [scheme] => http
    [host] => sub.domain.example.com
    [path] => /foo/bar
    [query] => hat=bowler&accessory=cane
)
```

Thus:

```
echo $parts['host'];
```

Gives you:

```
sub.domain.example.com
```