# PHP How to get the root url of a subdomain

Tags: php, apache, subdomain

I used to have my website into a domain like : `www.mydomain.com`
  But now i've created a subdomain 'test' : `www.test.mydomain.com` and i moved the whole project files there.

So far so good, the problem is that on my **php** libraries where i call db connection etc, i use the `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` which gives me the **URL** without the **subdomain** , e.x.

```
$file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];//gives me www.mydomain.com
```

**But i need to get the root with the subdomain, like** : www.test.mydomain.com

*I dont want to make a trick like to split the url and add the subdomain thing.*

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Might be duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292937/php-function-to-get-the-subdomain-of-a-url

Comment: `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` doesn't get any **URL**. It get the **absolute path** of current site document root. To obtain current host you have to use `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`

Answer (score 2):

You can try both:

```
$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]

$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']
```

Both will return the domain with the subdomain.

---

`$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]`

> The name of the server host under which the current script is executing. If the script is running on a virtual host, this will be the value defined for that virtual host.

`$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`

> Contents of the Host: header from the current request, if there is one.

You can read up on the difference between `$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]` and `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` at [HTTP_HOST vs. SERVER_NAME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297403/http-host-vs-server-name).

`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` will not work as stated in documentation

> The document root directory under which the current script is executing, as defined in the server's configuration file.

More information on `$_SERVER` at http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php.

Answer (score 2):

`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` does **not** contain the server name! It contains - as the name says - the `DOCUMENT_ROOT`. This is the directory where the filesystem starts that your webserver serves.

You should try `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` instead. This should work if your virtual server setup is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, after two hours searching , I spoke to the system admin and he cleared that he actually created an **alias domain** which it actually reacts as : `www.test.mydomain.com`.

I guess that is why i get the `www.mydomain.com`  **without the subdomain** when i call `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`.

Thanks, case closed.