# How php allow subdomains and grab data based on that subdomain

Tags: php

I am new to PHP world and I would like to be able to get any subdomain typed on the URL, for example if the URL is mike.myapp.com I would like to get "mike", if the URL is "james.myapp.com" I would like to get "james" and so on.

How this is done with PHP?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292937/php-function-to-get-the-subdomain-of-a-url

Comment: thank you guys for the helpful links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done that using this in the past:

```
$domain = 'myapp.com';

$sub = preg_replace('/\.' . preg_quote($domain) . '/i', '', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
```

This effectively gets rid of your domain and TLD and isolates the subdomain name.

You could just as well not using regex and use [`str_ireplace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-ireplace.php) replacing ".myapp.com" with an empty string.

Comment: Thank you this is what I was looking for :)