# Inserting the subdomain from current URL into PHP

Tags: php

Hi all this is my first question, and it might be that Im currently over confusing matters.... I have got a database config file which specifies the SQL database that is used. What I want to do is make it so that the database name is the same as the subdomain. Thus meaning that the same php can be used to access different databases. If you get me. Any help greatly appreciated.

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'databaseserver',
    'username' => 'admin',
    'password' => 'password',
    'database' => 'subdomain',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

Comment: How do you pass the subdomain to your configuration file ?

Comment: check $_SERVER variable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP function to get the subdomain of a URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292937/php-function-to-get-the-subdomain-of-a-url)