# PHP include path for dynamic subdomain

Tags: php, apache

I need to use a different PHP `php_value include_path` for each subdomain. The problem ist, that the subdomains are depending on the folders I have:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName subdomain.domain.com
        ServerAlias *.subdomain.domain.com
        VirtualDocumentRoot "/var/www/subdomains/%1"
</VirtualHost>
```

So I tried to save the current subdomain as a variable:

```
SetEnvIf Host "^([^.]*).subdomain.domain.com$" SUBDOMAIN=$1
Define CURR %{ENV:SUBDOMAIN}

php_value include_path ".:/var/www/subdomains/${CURR}/php"
```

But the content of `CURR` is "`%{ENV:SUBDOMAIN}`". Is it possible to use `Define` to get an env variable, which will work for `php_value`?

Comment: does the subdomains contain the same php code or each one have a different code ?

Comment: Each one have a different version like different git branches.

Comment: Use PHP to [determine the subdomain from the URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292937/php-function-to-get-the-subdomain-of-a-url)