# How do I get .htaccess to redirect from wildcard subdomain page to wildcard subdomain folder

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect

```
http://*.domain.co.uk/services.php
```

to

```
http://*.domain.co.uk/services
```

where `*` is a wildcard domain.

Ideally, htaccess should read the services page (as I have more than one) and redirect to the same services folder.

This is because I have changed my PHP pages to `folder/index.php`.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the htaccess file in your document root(s):

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([^/]+)\.php$ /$1/
```

You'll most likely need that trailing slash because if it's redirecting you to a directory, mod_dir will redirect **again** in order to add the trailing slash.

---

EDIT:

To exclude, you'll have to use mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.php
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)\.php$ /$1/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thank you. Do I place this in my public_html folder or in my wildcard subdomain folder? Also, do I need to put 
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase / before it

Comment: @JosephNaylor Whichever one is the document root. Essentially, the place you'd go to (for each of your hosts/subdomains) if you entered `http:*.domain.co.uk/`.

Comment: That didnt redirect - just said 404

Comment: @JosephNaylor Sorry, I left out a slash

Comment: @JosephNaylor No, this is part of mod_alias, if you have mod rewrite rules that process similar looking URIs then you'll need to rewrite the above directive for mod_rewrite, otherwise you don't need anything else

Comment: Thanks - one problem though. The url http://*.domain.co.uk/index.php is going to http://*.domain.co.uk/index/ which I dont want - how do I exclude that from this rule? If it helps I only have two named .php pages which need redirecting to folders

Comment: @JosephNaylor you'll need mod_rewrite for that, see edit above

Comment: @JosephNaylor Accept the answer so that your question gets marked as resolved